How can I directly jump to a failed test using pytest?
I open a terminal and run pytest in order to note the filename and linenumber of a failed test.
I then manually open the file and goto to the line.
I'm pretty sure there is an automatic solution though don't know where to start.
I tried pytest -x to no avail.
